# Is this a VALID and correct way to set up media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, stylesheet

```
<link id ="style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="other" href="regularStyles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"  media= "all and (mid-width: 767px) and (max-width:2049px) and (min-height:767px) and (max-height: 1538px)" href="notePads.css"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" media= "all and (min width: 319px) and (max width: 1281px) and not desktop and not (width: 352px; height: 416px) " href="NormalTouchPhones.css" />
```

Is this a VALID way to set up a stylesheet (NormalTouchPhones.css) targeting all regular touch-phones, but not small nokia. wich has excact widht of 352px, and heigth of 416 px? And then this is for the smallest.

```
media= "all and (mid widht: 175px) and (max-widht: 353px) and (min-height: 207px) and (max-height: 321px)and not desktop" href="smallNokias.css"
```

I also have this in my index file.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8.css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

I have also set my stylesheet's descending, Desktop's at the top, then my Notepads, then my bigger Touch-phones, then the smallest of phones, like Nokia's and Sony-Ericcson's.
Will it work correctly? Thank You for any comments, both for improving or hopefully confirm I have approached this correctly :)

Comment: You should rethink your Values. An IPohne and most other pohnes too have a width of 320px (480px in landscape). That should be you min. Width! Have a look: http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/simple-device-diagram-responsive-design-planning

Comment: I had something misspelled for Nokia Stylesheet, edited now.

Comment: Ok, is that not the case in My NormalTouchPhones.css?  (min width: 319px) Or will something like Nokia.css overwrite it?

Comment: So min width 320, not 319?

Comment: Yeah id ont think you Need to do -1. But another theortical Thing - What happens when I acess your site with a Display small then175 px? You shouldn't put a min-width into the smallest media query, instead user `Body{min-width:175px;}` in your css

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, is there such a thing smaller than 175px?, possibly put in, or max.width 175px? :)

Comment: I Don't think there is, but you never know :) I would say just try it with the Nokia. I havent done something like that yet

Comment: Thanks, will try it out, as Nokia N80, N90 and E70, have 352x480, and the rest of Nokias and Sony's is below 240x320, and as you said touch phones start at 320x480. and of course 480x320, it seemed a logical way of eliminating the 3 Nokias from Touch-styling :)

Comment: You can make a style for all under 320px that hides all Content and just Displays a Text like: `Sorry we dont Support your Screen size`

Comment: @j_s_stack What's wrong with allowing the user to scroll horizontally if they have such a narrow screen?

Comment: I have done something like that for IE8 and below,cannot seem to float my css-navigation bar, and have it act as a drop down menu :/

Comment: But at least the stylesheet for touch works on my galaxyS3, so it doesn't litter the code with my not nokia, happy to see that :)

A little off topic here now but, 
thinking I can at least display some text and some old fashion style, like non styled links, wich are hidden with Disply:none, on normal pages. I have read, that it is not a good idea to have this approach, hiding divs, at my bottom of html, but like with ie8, where drop down menu, just is a list of block-items, how can I otherwise solve this? 

Any clues? :)

Comment: good point, the ones with that small screens are probably used to it, and not expecting to much.

Comment: I seem to have one problem with this setup, if My Nokia stylesheet is at the bottom, it overrides my TouchPhone stylesheet.

Comment: I tried, to set up like this

 <link rel="stylesheet" media= "all and (max-widht: 240px) and (max-height: 320px) and not desktop" href =" smallest.css" />

But this overwrites my previous, even thou I don't think my Galaxys3 is true, within that last statement. What am I doing wrong, or overlooking here? I know stylesheets function, like the last stylesheet "wins", but isn't that only if it is true?
Why is then tha nokia stylesheet, true for android? :o

Answer (score 0):

```
<link id ="style" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="other" href="android.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media= "all and (mid-width: 767px) and (max-width:2049px) and (min-height:767px) and (max-height: 1538px)" href="notePads.css"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" media= "all and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 1281px) and not (width: 352px; height: 416px) and not desktop, (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2.0) " href="android.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media= "all and (max-widht: 240px) and (max-height: 320px) and not desktop" href =" smallest.css" />
```

This is working out now, thanks for guidance :)

Only seem to be one problem, I put in (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:2.0), and this targets google chrome, on my mobile.

So that Google chrome, and the standard Internet browser, vies the same content on my Galaxy s3. Perhaps wrong to do this? 
Is google Chrome 2.0, and safari not? The same stylesheet without device-pixel-ratio set to 2.0, gives my mobile internet what I want, but not google chrome in mobile. Has no effect in my desktop chrome browser thou.

But safari.. On macbook air, I view the same as on mobile, and ideeas to why, and any way to solve this?